# Default path param in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I would like to add a dynamic default path param in my routes.

For exemple, i would like to redirect the user to '/timesheets/2016-07' when he goes to '/timesheets', 2016-07 being the current month.

How could I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
indexRoute: { onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('/timesheets/' + formattedDate()) },
```

You can reference the documentation on this here:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.